# Django: migration to NullBooleanField fails with IntegrityError "contains null values"

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-migrations

I'm working in Django 1.7 and trying to migrate a database field called `is_dispensing` from an existing `BooleanField` to a `NullBooleanField`.

My migration file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('frontend', '0007_practice_is_dispensing'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='practice',
            name='is_dispensing',
            field=models.NullBooleanField(),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Running `manage.py migrate` fails with this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "is_dispensing" contains null values
```

The field in my models file:

```
is_dispensing = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True)
```

Previously it was:

```
is_dispensing = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and when I added it, I was asked to provide a default value, which I set as None.

I find this message confusing - I'm trying to migrate the column type to `NullBooleanField`, so why can't it contain null values? That's the whole point of this column type, isn't it? :)

UPDATE: Another thing that's confusing: if I go into Postgres and look at the table that's supposed to have the column, it doesn't actually have an `is_dispensing` column at all.

Comment: I think what's going on here is that the first migration (creating the `BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)` didn't execute in full, because Django 1.7 doesn't allow pure `BooleanField` fields to have null values. So `makemigrations` ran but then `migrate` failed. I... think? I still don't really understand how I can get an `IntegrityError` when the column doesn't exist in the database!

Comment: blank=True only affects from generation (in the admin for example). It doesn't affect the actual database tables. Try manage.py migrate --fake. This will put an entry in your migrations table. You will need to check the database tables to see if they actually have NOT NULL or not and update them manually. Not a perfect solution, but I would need to see the migration files to fix it all through django migrations.

Answer (score 0):

non-unique combinations of slugs and your app in the project table can cause this error. I fixed it by ensuring that all of my project slugs were unique by manually editing them.

you can add blank = true foreignkey definition, delete all migrations and run migraions again...